# Spring MVC annotation error "No adapter for handler - Does your handler implement a supported interface like Controller?"

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have an existing Spring MVC apps written in 2.5.

I wanted to use the new annotation controller.  I somewhat see that it is really flexible and would answer my other needs.

My problem is, it seems I cannot mix them both.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

    <context:component-scan
            base-package="com.test.web" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />

    <!-- Controller Mappings Here -->
    <bean id="homeController" class="com.test.web.HomeController">
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="120" />
    </bean> 

    //other plain old spring mvc controller
```

When I ran my app and hit the home page, I get below error:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: No adapter for handler [com.test.web.HomeController@cca07b]: Does your handler implement a supported interface like Controller?

I am not sure but I think something is conflicting. This is a fairly large Spring MVC apps and I don't want to change those modules that were working already using the old Spring Base Controller.

My goal is to only use the annotation controller on my new enhancement.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to declare `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` and `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter`. The context has these registered by default, along with adapters for old-style controllers.

When you declare them explicitly like this, the default ones are removed, and the context will only support the ones you declare.

Comment: Hi Skaffman,

I tried what you have suggested but I am getting a 404 when I removed these declaration.

I already commented out the controller in my mappings thinking that it will autodetect my @controller.
 
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
  <property name="mappings">
   <props>
    <!-- <prop key="/home.htm">homeController</prop> -->

Comment: I forgot to mention that I still have SimpleUrlHandlerMapping configured in my configuration file

Comment: I am facing this same problem.Were you able to get a solution for this ?